# Get window icon: GetClassLong VS SendMessage

Tags: c++, winapi

There are two methods to get window icon if i know his handle:

```
SendMessage(HWND,0x7F lParam, wParam)
```

and

```
GetClassLong(HWND, -14|-34)
```

But even if I get icon from window with GetClassLong i can't set new icon with SetClassLong, but successfully set new icon with SendMessage. 
I need to know: why in some times work second get method, but doen't work first method. And why always from SendMessage(WN_SETICON) and doen't work SetClassLong(HWND, -14|-34, HICON)?

Comment: Why are you using magic constants? Perhaps if you stopped doing that it might be easier to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

[`GetClassLong`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633580(v=vs.85).aspx) retrieves `long`s from the window class.

A window class is a blueprint for creating a window of a specified type, *not* the window itself.
It can contain quite a lot of defaults, like the default icon, and the default small icon.

But a window is only based on it, it can override everything.
Thus, setting the windowclass' icon does not modify any already created classes, you must send a message to the window instead.
And reading the windowclass-data gets you stale data, which might or might not still be relevant to the window.

As an aside, `-14|-34` would be `GCL_HICON|GCL_HICONSM`, or `-2`, which does not actually make sense.
Explicitly say that you read with both indices one after the other.

Answer (score 2):

-14 is `GCL_HICON` which is the (optional resource) icon for the *class* specified when its registered.

A specific window can subsequently specify its own icon (`WM_SETICON`), subsequent changes to 
`GCL_HICON` won't affect it.

I also doubt you can attempt to pull `GCL_HICON | GCL_HICONSM`, if they were different what would the value be?

Answer (score 2):

A few additional things:

1) Don't use magic numbers for Windows API constant values. Use `WM_GETICON`, not `0x7F`. Use the `GCL_` names as mentioned by the other answers.

2) You switched `wParam` and `lParam` in your `SendMessage()`. `wParam` comes first.

3) Don't use `GetClassLong()`; it is not 64-bit safe (and icon handles are pointers). Use `GetClassLongPtr()` instead. Also substitute `GCLP_` for `GCL_` in your named constants.

4) Don't try to replace `|` in your `GetClassLong()` with `||` or with an array of indices and expect that to work either. You don't have a choice but to make two calls.